# ClassCircularityError: java/lang/WeakPairMap$Pair$Weak in JUnit5, Springboot, Pact Project in Debug Mode

Tags: junit5, pact

We have a spring boot project using JUnit 5 and Pact. We are using OpenJDK 17. When we run the JUnit 5 tests, we don't face any problems, but when we want to debug them, we get the below problem.

**Note**: I tried many versions of JUnit Jupiter and Pact dependencies but could not solve the issue.

When we remove the pact junit5 consumer and provider dependencies, the debug works fine.

I also tried Async Stack Traces -> Instrumenting Agent option on/off in IntelliJ but it did not solve anything.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Error Message:**

```html
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52218', transport: 'socket'
Internal Error occurred.
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverSafely(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:132)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: MethodSelector [className = 'com.emirates.ocsl.skeleton.ct.tests.SkeletonCT', methodName = 'iGetResponseSuccessfully', methodParameterTypes = ''] resolution failed
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.discovery.AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.selectorProcessed(AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.java:39)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:103)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.run(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:46)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:152)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/lang/WeakPairMap$Pair$Weak
    at java.base/java.lang.WeakPairMap$Pair.weak(WeakPairMap.java:201)
    at java.base/java.lang.WeakPairMap.putIfAbsent(WeakPairMap.java:123)
    at java.base/java.lang.Module.implAddReads(Module.java:488)
    at java.base/java.lang.Module.implAddReads(Module.java:449)
    at java.base/java.lang.System$2.addReads(System.java:2335)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.Modules.addReads(Modules.java:90)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.lambda$getDynamicModule$1(Proxy.java:918)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue$Memoizer.get(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:329)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue.computeIfAbsent(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:205)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.getDynamicModule(Proxy.java:908)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.mapToModule(Proxy.java:846)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.<init>(Proxy.java:651)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.<init>(Proxy.java:656)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.lambda$getProxyConstructor$0(Proxy.java:429)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue$Memoizer.get(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:329)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue.computeIfAbsent(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:205)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyConstructor(Proxy.java:427)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:1037)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser$1.run(AnnotationParser.java:302)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser$1.run(AnnotationParser.java:300)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.annotationForMap(AnnotationParser.java:300)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:289)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:121)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSelectAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:102)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:146)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:262)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:121)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:73)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:4068)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:4057)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3940)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(AnnotatedElement.java:292)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.isAnnotationPresent(Class.java:3950)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:136)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils.isAnnotated(AnnotationUtils.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.predicates.IsTestableMethod.test(IsTestableMethod.java:52)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.predicates.IsTestMethod.test(IsTestMethod.java:23)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.predicates.IsTestableMethod.test(IsTestableMethod.java:26)
    at java.base/java.util.function.Predicate.lambda$or$2(Predicate.java:101)
    at java.base/java.util.function.Predicate.lambda$or$2(Predicate.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:1345)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.isMethodPresent(ReflectionUtils.java:1244)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.predicates.IsTestClassWithTests.hasTestOrTestFactoryOrTestTemplateMethods(IsTestClassWithTests.java:50)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.predicates.IsTestClassWithTests.test(IsTestClassWithTests.java:46)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.predicates.IsTestClassWithTests.test(IsTestClassWithTests.java:27)
    at java.base/java.util.function.Predicate.lambda$or$2(Predicate.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.MethodSelectorResolver.resolve(MethodSelectorResolver.java:87)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.MethodSelectorResolver.resolve(MethodSelectorResolver.java:75)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.lambda$resolve$2(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1602)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:189)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:92)
    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 0):

After long debugging hours, the below configuration in pom.xml works. ktor libraries create conflict in our Springboot, webflux, junit5, openJDK17 project.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${pact.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
                <artifactId>ktor-network-tls-certificates</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
                <artifactId>ktor-server-netty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
                <artifactId>ktor-http-jvm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.consumer</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${pact.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
                <artifactId>ktor-network-tls-certificates</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
                <artifactId>ktor-server-netty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
                <artifactId>ktor-http-jvm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```